# How can I handle nested case statements without an indentation tree?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I occasionally run into a minor issue where I've got a set of nested case statements, which becomes cumbersome to handle. Is there any technique / pattern I can use to possibly have a list of functions (which would be equivalent to the examples's `case ...` statements), evaluate all of them, and pick the first that matches a pattern (example: `Right x`)?

A specific issue I have with putting them in a list, is they won't necessarily be of the same type (the monomorphism restriction I think). For example the following:

```
  let possibleTags = [
          parse (parseFileReference) "file reference" xStr
        , parse (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag" xStr
        ]
```

Produces the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘GitDiffReference’ with ‘FileReference’
  Expected type: Either ParseError FileReference
    Actual type: Either ParseError GitDiffReference
• In the expression:
    parse (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag" xStr
  In the expression:
    [parse (parseFileReference) "file reference" xStr,
     parse (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag" xStr]
  In an equation for ‘possibleTags’:
      possibleTags
        = [parse (parseFileReference) "file reference" xStr,
           parse (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag" xStr]
```

---

```
abc :: Int -> String
abc = undefined

abc2 :: Int -> Float
abc2 = undefined

abc3 :: Int -> Int
abc3 = undefined

example :: Int -> Maybe String
example x = case abc x of 
  ("yes") -> Just "abc"
  ("no")  -> case abc2 x of
               1.0 -> Just "abc2"
               2.0 -> case abc3 x of
                        100 -> Just "abc3"
                        200 -> Nothing
```

I'm ideally looking for something like the below (not valid code):

```
-- Psuedo code
example :: Int -> Maybe String
example = 
 if (abc x && "yes") then Just "abc"
 if (abc2 x && 1.0) then Just "abc2"
 if (abc3 x && 100) then Just "abc3"
```

The problem with using `if` conditional is I can't(to my knowledge) do a pattern match, for example `if (Just x)`.

Comment: The first thing I question here is why this is all `IO`. You have completely arbitrary print statements in the middle (possibly debugging statements) and no other I/O. Eliminating the `IO` monad dependency would probably open you up to some more reductions between `Maybe` and `Either`.

Comment: The reason for IO is because `fileReferenceContent` is of type `FileReference -> IO (Maybe Text)`. I could possibly provide a simpler example if it helps.

Comment: Perhaps you should craft a `[IO (Maybe (Either String Text))]`, with `Nothing` meaning "try the next case in the list", and `Just` meaning "stop here, we have a result".

Comment: That's not the monomorphism restriction by the way. It's just a requirement of homogeneous lists that all the elements have the same type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Translating the exact example (keeping the non-exhaustive pattern matching as it is):

```
import Data.Foldable


example2 :: Int -> Maybe String
example2 x = asum tests
   where
   tests =
      [ case abc x of 
         "yes" -> Just "abc"
         "no"  -> Nothing
      , case abc2 x of
         1.0 -> Just "abc2"
         2.0 -> Nothing
      , case abc3 x of
         100 -> Just "abc3"
         200 -> Nothing
      ]
```

Answer (score 5):

At least when the result is `Maybe`, this looks like a clear-cut use case for the [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) instance:

```
example x = ("abc" <$ guard (abc x=="yes"))
         <|>("abc2" <$ guard (abc2 x==1))
         <|>("abc3" <$ guard (abc3 x==100))
```

Comment: If we need to use pattern matching (instead of `Eq`), we can also abuse `do` notation or even monad comprehensions, relying on `fail "..."` being `Nothing`.

Comment: Note that guard is now found in the `Control.Monad` module.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to work with your original example. A contrived example like your second one is unlikely to simplify nicely, whereas your first one looks like monad transformer code is actually something you might see in production.

Looking for a general "if-then-case" statement like you seem to is not going to end fruitfully. That's because case-statements are really the catch-all in Haskell, and reductions are going to be more specific, not more general, than `case`. So with that in mind, let's take a look at your code.

````
parseLine :: Text -> IO (Either String Text)
parseLine x = do
  let xStr = convertString x :: String
  case parse (parseFileReference) "file reference" xStr of
    Right z -> do
      print z
      fileReferenceContent z >>= \case
        Just v' -> return2x $ "```\n" <> v' <> "```"
        Nothing -> return $ Left "Unable to parse"
    Left _ -> case parse (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag" xStr of
        Right z -> do
          print z
          return2x $ ""
        Left _ -> case parse (parsePossibleTag) "possible tag" xStr of
          Right _ -> return $ Left $ "Tag that failed to match: " ++ xStr
          Left _ -> return2x x
````

In each case, when you parse, you ignore the contents if it's a `Left`. So let's strip out that pointless data that you ignore.

```
eitherToMaybe :: Either a b -> Maybe b
eitherToMaybe (Left _) = Nothing
eitherToMaybe (Right x) = Just x

parse' :: Foo0 -> String -> String -> Maybe Bar -- where Foo0 and Bar are the correct types
parse' foo s0 s1 = eitherToMaybe $ parse foo s0 s1
```

Then call `parse'` instead of `parse`. This doesn't, as yet, improve anything. But let's refactor a bit more and then we'll see what it gets us. I want all of the "success" cases (which were `Right z` before and are `Just z` in the new `parse'` code) to be in a `where` block.

````
parseLine x = do
  let xStr = convertString x :: String
  case parse' (parseFileReference) "file reference" xStr of
    Just z -> fileRef z
    Nothing -> case parse' (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag" xStr of
        Just z -> gitDiff z
        Nothing -> case parse' (parsePossibleTag) "possible tag" xStr of
          Just _ -> tagMatch xStr
          Nothing -> return2x x
    where fileRef z = do
                print z
                fileReferenceContent z >>= \case
                      Just v' -> return2x $ "```\n" <> v' <> "```"
                      Nothing -> return $ Left "Unable to parse"
          gitDiff z = do
                print z
                return2x ""
          tagMatch xStr = do
                return (Left $ "Tag that failed to match: " ++ xStr)
````

Once again, no real benefit yet. But here's the thing: `Maybe` has an `Alternative` instance that does exactly what you want, whereas `Either` does not. Specifically, it will select the first successful match while ignoring the others. Let's pull out the matches and then go from there.

````
parseLine :: Text -> IO (Either String Text)
parseLine x = do
  let xStr = convertString x :: String
  case parseFile xStr of
    Just z -> fileRef z
    Nothing -> case parseDiff xStr of
        Just z -> gitDiff z
        Nothing -> case parseTag xStr of
          Just _ -> tagMatch xStr
          Nothing -> return2x x
    where parseFile = parse' (parseFileReference) "file reference"
          parseDiff = parse' (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag"
          parseTag  = parse' (parsePossibleTag) "possible tag"
          fileRef z = do
                print z
                fileReferenceContent z >>= \case
                      Just v' -> return2x $ "```\n" <> v' <> "```"
                      Nothing -> return $ Left "Unable to parse"
          gitDiff z = do
                print z
                return2x ""
          tagMatch xStr = do
                return (Left $ "Tag that failed to match: " ++ xStr)
````

Now here's where the magic happens. `Alternative` for `Maybe` will select the first successful match. So we're going to use `asum`, which sums up a list of alternatives using the `Alternative` instance.

```
parseLine :: Text -> IO (Either String Text)
parseLine x = do
  let xStr = convertString x :: String
  let result = asum [
                fileRef <$> parseFile xStr,
                gitDiff <$> parseDiff xStr,
                tagMatch xStr <$ parseTag xStr -- Not a typo, the operator is (<$) since you ignore the value
               ]
  maybe failure id result
    where ...
          failure = return2x x
```

At the end, we're left with `result :: Maybe (IO (Either String Text)). If it exists, we want to return it unmodified. If it doesn't, we want to fall back to`failure`. So we use`maybe`, which is more compact than a full case statement here.

Finally, in `fileRef` we can factor out the pattern of "custom error message on failure".

```
maybeToEither :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
maybeToEither x Nothing  = Left x
maybeToEither _ (Just y) = Right y
```

Then that statement becomes

````
fileRef z = do
     print z
     value <- maybeToEither "Unable to parse" <$> fileReferenceContent z
     return $ (\v' -> "```\n" <> v' <> "```") <$> value
````

So the final code looks like

````
eitherToMaybe :: Either a b -> Maybe b
eitherToMaybe (Left _) = Nothing
eitherToMaybe (Right x) = Just x

parse' :: Foo0 -> String -> String -> Maybe Bar -- where Foo0 and Bar are the correct types
parse' foo s0 s1 = eitherToMaybe $ parse foo s0 s1

maybeToEither :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
maybeToEither x Nothing  = Left x
maybeToEither _ (Just y) = Right y

parseLine :: Text -> IO (Either String Text)
parseLine x = do
  let xStr = convertString x :: String
  let result = asum [
                fileRef <$> parseFile xStr,
                gitDiff <$> parseDiff xStr,
                tagMatch xStr <$ parseTag xStr
               ]
  maybe failure id result
    where parseFile = parse' (parseFileReference) "file reference"
          parseDiff = parse' (parseGitDiffReference) "git diff tag"
          parseTag  = parse' (parsePossibleTag) "possible tag"
          fileRef z = do
                print z
                value <- maybeToEither "Unable to parse" <$> fileReferenceContent z
                return $ (\v' -> "```\n" <> v' <> "```") <$> value
          gitDiff z = do
                print z
                return2x ""
          tagMatch xStr = do
                return (Left $ "Tag that failed to match: " ++ xStr)
          failure = return2x x
````

It's not shorter than the original code, but it has less nested case alternatives, and it certainly reads more linearly.